# How do I change an onclick function to have multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change a button's onclick function to remove one function and add two functions. This is my current code

```
    var random;

    function number(){
        var random =Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*20))

    }

function show(){
    var display = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML= random;
}

function start(){
    var random =Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*20))
    var button = document.getElementById('button').innerHTML="I give up!!";
    var change = document.getElementById("button").onclick = show; number;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing here.  Why are you setting equality twice?  ... among other things I don't understand.  Are you able to even get one function working on your button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 event listeners to your button

```
function start(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*20)),
        button = document.getElementById('button').innerHTML="I give up!!";
        changeButton = document.getElementById("button");

    changeButton.addEventListener('click', show);
    changeButton.addEventListener('click', number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `onclick` an anonymous function and include both functions in it:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    show();
    number(); 
};
```